# Unchecked runtime.lastError when using Chrome API

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I use `chrome.fileSystem` API in my app to open a file. When I click the `Cancel` button of the file chooser dialog, an error occurs:

> Unchecked `runtime.lastError` while running `fileSystem.chooseEntry`: User cancelled

How to fix this error?

Comment: probably you should use TRY ... CATCH block.

Comment: @Seti Won't help in this case.

Comment: So maybe you can give us the code you use around chrome.filesystem then?

Comment: @Seti See my answer as to why `try ... catch` can't catch it.

Comment: @Seti, You don't solve it with a trycatch, but by reading it from the callback. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/45603880/632951 for solution.

Comment: Dang, some of my Chrome extensions are throwing these errors.

Answer (score 117, accepted):

This error is not important in this case, but I'll explain it and how to get rid of it.

### What is this error?

Chrome APIs are mostly asynchronous: you have a callback that is called when the operation completes.

In case of `chrome.fileSystem.chooseEntry`, the chosen entry (or entries) will be passed to a callback:

```
chrome.fileSystem.chooseEntry(
  {/* options */},
  function(entry) {
    // This is the callback for the API call; you can do something with entry
  }
);
```

However, the API is not *guaranteed* to yield a result. For example, as in your case, the user may refuse to provide access by clicking "Cancel". Then there is no entry to work with, and you might want some explanation as to why that happened. How to raise an error without polluting all callbacks with an extra "error" argument?

Usually, Chrome deals with this by setting a global variable, `chrome.runtime.lastError`, at the time the callback is called. **It is uniform across Chrome async APIs to use this instead of an error argument.** In fact, quoting the `chrome.fileSystem` docs:

> All failures are notified via chrome.runtime.lastError.

- If everything is all right, it will be `undefined`.
- If there is a problem, it will be non-empty, and `chrome.runtime.lastError.message` will explain what's wrong.

However, some callbacks did not check for this error variable. This may indicate a programming error, and Chrome added checks that `chrome.runtime.lastError` is actually checked (evaluated) in a callback. If not, it considers this to be an unhandled exception, and throws this error.

### **Why do I say it's not important?**

While it's an error, it won't break execution of your program (it's thrown at the end of an async task), and won't really be displayed to your users.

And while I say it's not important, you should check you program's logic. It may or may not be all right - this is intended to be a (stern) warning.

### **Why does it exist?**

To warn, *you*, the developer, that your code **probably** tries to use a result that does not exist, because something went wrong.

It's possible you're already checking for an error, e.g.

```
if (entry) {
  // Process entry
} else {
  // Something went wrong (but what?)
}
```

Chrome does not employ complex heuristics to see if your code expects this possibility. As noted, errors are reported via `chrome.runtime.lastError`, and you're expected to check it.

Note that this error is only raised when something bad *does* occur, and not when the API call finishes normally.

### **Can I catch it?**

Not really; it's not raised by your code, but the cleanup code that handles async tasks in Chrome API; therefore using `try ... catch` in your callback won't help. Since it's asynchronous, using `try` around the original API call won't help either.

### **What to do with it?**

You should add logic to your callback that checks for problems the way Chrome expects it, and probably react to it.

```
function(entry) {
  if(chrome.runtime.lastError) {
    // Something went wrong
    console.warn("Whoops.. " + chrome.runtime.lastError.message);
    // Maybe explain that to the user too?
  } else {
    // No errors, you can use entry
  }
}
```

As long as Chrome sees that you *checked* the value when there is an error (that is, evaluated it within your callback), the error will not be thrown.

Comment: Thought so, but if he had addached the code he was using, and we saw that his callbacks do not clean the errors - we could answer it faster.

Comment: @zcfrank1st No problem. Also clarified that it's not the _only_ way to check for errors, but a unified way across Chrome APIs.

Comment: Incredible answer! Thank you for taking time to write this.

Comment: This type of answer is why I love stackexchange :-)

Comment: @Xan, You seem to be supporting using a global  `chrome.runtime.lastError` instead of using an error argument for each callback. Why so? Wouldn't giving each callback its own error argument be much cleaner?

Comment: I never said I consider this to be good architecture, but it is what it is - a design decision somewhere early in Chrome APIs. I'm not part of Chrome dev team, so I wouldn't be able to tell you why this was chosen.

Comment: @Xan, you say "Can I catch it? Not really", but don't address whether it can be handled by a `window.onerror` handler. From what I can tell, a runtime error doesn't trigger a global error handler, but I'd be happy to be proven wrong.

Comment: Checking the error works, but why when I debug, lastError is undefined in the callback? It's logged to the console before the callback even runs, so when the callback runs it's undefined already. Seems to be a problem specific to debugging.

Answer (score 7):

Late to the party, but here's how I suppressed the error in a `chrome.windows.remove()` call, in case it helps anyone else.  Instead of

```
chrome.windows.remove(foo);  // unconditional; runtime.lastError not checked
```

I used

```
chrome.windows.remove(
        foo,
        function ignore_error() { void chrome.runtime.lastError; }
);
```

[`void`](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/types%20%26%20grammar/ch2.md#void-operator) evaluates its operand and then returns `undefined`.  I think this code fairly effectively documents that its purpose is to ignore errors :) .

For brevity, `ignore_error()` could be pulled out of this call and used for multiple `chrome` API calls, or the name `ignore_error` could be omitted.

**Update** In ES6, you can use the shorter [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) syntax:

```
chrome.windows.remove( foo, ()=>void chrome.runtime.lastError );
```

<sup>Tested in Chrome 64</sup>

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'remove' of undefined

Comment: @Jordan `chrome.windows` is part of the extension API.  If you try to use this from a regular Web page, `chrome.windows` doesn't exist, giving you the error you saw.

Answer (score 5):

For this type of errors `try catch` won't be helpful. Instead you can access the global variable `chrome.runtime.lastError` as @xan mentioned in his awesome response above(by the way you should read it and upvote it!).

Now, here I provide an example that can be used:

```
function catchLastError(){
  if(chrome.runtime.lastError){
    console.log("error: ", chrome.runtime.lastError);
  }else{
    // some code goes here.
  }
}

chrome.fileSystem.chooseEntry(yourEntry,catchLastError);
```

Answer (score 0):

This error has something to do with some google chrome extensions per [Already addressed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59914490/how-to-handle-unchecked-runtime-lasterror-the-message-port-closed-before-a-res). I disabled all of my extensions and the error went away. After playing with each one of them some more, I found that Natural Reader Text to Speech extension was the one causing it. It's highly possible you have an extension causing this. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Just to share my case;

The error disappears when I remove the line;

```
res.end()
```

from the http headers on nodejs app