# How to replace/upgrade a Chrome extension with another?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

My team owns a Chrome extension, and the other team has a similar extension but sooner will be deprecated, so we will take over all their existing users. Here comes the question - is there a way to migrate users from their extension to ours seamless? I.e. is there a way to auto-upgrade to our extension from user end?

Comment: Not unless you want to maintain two separate versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no seamless way, as for obvious security reasons extensions can't install other extensions (even with `"management"` permission), but here's a possible upgrade path.

I'll call the "old" extension A and assume its ID is `"extension_a_id"`, and the "new" extension B and assume its ID is `extension_b_id".

1. Make sure that extensions can talk to each other. Unless you specifically define [`"externally_connectable"`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/externally_connectable) in the manifest, that should be the case by default; if you do, make sure that extension B's includes the `"extension_a_id"` ID and vice versa.
2. Update extension B to include code responding to requests from A **in all following steps**. Do not proceed until you're reasonably sure most of the install base has this version (maybe wait a week or so).

   ```js
   //// Extension B (background code) ////
   chrome.runtime.onMessageExternal.addListener(
     function(message, sender, sendResponse) {
       if(sender.id && sender.id == "extension_A_id") {
         /* ..processing code.. */
       }
     }
   );
   ```
3. In extension A, add a check that extension B is installed. Do so by pinging it:

   ```js
   //// Extension A ////
   chrome.runtime.onStartup.addListener(function() {
     isNewInstalled(function(response) {
       if(response) {
         transferPreferences(response.versionB); // See step 5
       } else {
         // Nag user to install, see step 4
       }
     });
   });        

   function isNewInstalled(callback) {
     chrome.runtime.sendMessage(
       "extension_B_id",
       {areYouThere: true},
       passResponseOrFalse(callback)
     );
   }

   function passResponseOrFalse(callback) {
     return function(response) {
       // It's important to evaluate chrome.runtime.lastError
       //   to prevent uncatchable exception, see http://stackoverflow.com/q/28431505
       if(chrome.runtime.lastError || !response) {
         callback(false);
       } else {
         callback(response);
       }
     }
   }

   //// Extension B (processing code) ////
   // Send version number just in case
   if(message.areYouThere) sendResponse({
     versionB: chrome.runtime.getManifest().version
   });
   ```
4. If extension B is not installed in step 3, nag the user to install it: show a page that explains why it is needed to upgrade and link to the CWS listing. This step requires user input.
5. If the extension B is already installed in step 3, transfer user options over and self-uninstall:

   ```js
   //// Extension A ////
   function transferPreferences(versionB) {
     /* ..validate version of B.. */
     var prefs = {};
     /* ..fill prefs with data that needs to be transfered (JSON-encodable).. */
     chrome.runtime.sendMessage(
       "extension_B_id",
       {
         versionA: chrome.runtime.getManifest().version,
         preferences: prefs
       },
       passResponseOrFalse(goodbyeCruelWorld)
     );
   }

   function goodbyeCruelWorld(response) {
     if(response.processed) {
       // Does not require management permission
       chrome.management.uninstallSelf();
     } else {
       console.warn("It is not my time to die yet.");
     }
   }

   //// Extension B, processing code ////
   if(message.preferences) {
     /* ..validate message.versionA and process message.preferences.. */
     sendResponse({processed: true});
   }
   ```
6. When extension B is installed, message the (possibly installed) extension A that the transfer can start immediately:

   ```js
   //// Extension B, background code ////
   chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function(details) {
     /* ..maybe check details.reason and new version.. */
     chrome.runtime.sendMessage(
       "extension_A_id",
       {iAmHere: true, versionB: chrome.runtime.getManifest().version},
       ignoreResponse
     );
   });

   function ignoreResponse(response) {
     // Again, evaluate to avoid exceptions;
     //   if needed, this is the place to check if A is still installed
     return chrome.runtime.lastError;
   }

   //// Extension A, background code ////
   chrome.runtime.onMessageExternal.addListener(
     function(message, sender, sendResponse) {
       if(sender.id && sender.id == "extension_B_id") {
         if(message.iAmHere) {
           sendResponse({
             versionA: chrome.runtime.getManifest().version
           });
           transferPreferences(message.versionB);
         }
       }
     }
   );
   ```
7. Publish an update to extension B with all of the above.

Result:

- Users that have B installed won't notice anything, since `ignoreResponse` will gobble up the messaging error;
- Users that have both installed will initiate transfer as soon as B updates and it will quietly finish;
- Users that only have A will be nagged on every extension restart to install B instead, upon which the transfer will start automatically.

One last concern is not to clobber the preferences of B with ones from A; left as an exercise to the reader (and also depends on the implementation).

Comment: Please note: I have not actually tested the code above, it may contain silly mistakes and/or typos; edits to that effect are welcome.

Comment: Thanks, it very helpful!