# Can I have more than one version of my extension available on the Chrome webstore at the same time?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-web-store

Is it possible to have two versions of my extension published on the Chrome webstore (one public and the other unlisted)?  If so, will they have different extension ids?

I already have a public extension published on the Chrome webstore.  I would like to make modifications that only beta testers have access to.  When I am ready to release the extension publicly, do I only need to mark the extension from unlisted to public in the developer dashboard?  Will the original version be removed from the webstore or is there a way to install previous versions?

Comment: You will need to use a completely separate beta listing.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to have two versions of my extension published on the Chrome webstore (one public and the other unlisted)? If so, will they have different extension ids?

They will be separate extensions, so there will be separate IDs. However, this is perfectly normal practice.

AMO, unlike CWS, offers "beta" versions as a separate update stream. But CWS has no such concept.

> I already have a public extension published on the Chrome webstore. I would like to make modifications that only beta testers have access to.

You'll need a separate extension. Of course, beta-testers will be inconvenienced by the fact that data is not shared between the two; but that's to be expected of a beta-test. Providing a data export/import mechanism would be helpful though.

> When I am ready to release the extension publicly, do I only need to mark the extension from unlisted to public in the developer dashboard? Will the original version be removed from the webstore or is there a way to install previous versions?

Ideally, you want to replace the old "stable" version with the new one. That would make the old version unavailable, but provide a smooth transition for your existing users.

If you want to keep the "legacy" version separately available, you can of course just publish publicly the "new" version. But you have the concern about migrating your user base (and its data) with it.

Consider [this answer I wrote previously](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34336437/934239) on inter-extension migration.

Comment: Thank you for the very thorough response.  If I understand you correctly, the extension id is changed *each* time an extension is updated?  That is what happened in my case.  I uploaded a new version in the developer panel but did not publish it immediately (I clicked 'Save draft' and exited).  I went back in the next day and clicked the 'Publish' button.  When it appeared in the webstore an hour or so later, it had a different extension id than the original.