# Return value missed within the closure after browserified

Tags: javascript, gulp, browserify

My original script looks like this:

```
(function() {
    // result = doSomeWorks()
    return result;
})();
```

Which I can get a return value from APIs like `chrome.tabs.executeScript` or `execute_script` of selenium/webdriver.

But after the script being browserified (http://pastebin.com/7dBJuGzL), the return value seems just missed. I always get a `null` value from the above APIs.

Is there any solution/workaround for this? Or maybe trying to get the return value from a browserified script it just not idiomatic to Browserify?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `funcion` or `function` ?

Comment: Oh, typo on SO. It was function in my script.