# Chrome captureVisibleTab does not work on MSWindows

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

So I want wrote some code which will allow me to take a screenshot of the page when a button is pressed on my website. The code works, but the only problem is that I have to click on the chrome extension first, and then I can click on the button for it to take the screenshot. I guess that's because the active tab is not invoked. Any ideas? 
This error does not occur in Ubuntu and Mac, only windows.

This is the error: Unchecked runtime.lastError while running tabs.captureVisibleTab: The 'activeTab' permission is not in effect because this extension has not been in invoked.

**Chrome version**

```
52.0.2743.116 m (64-bit)
```

**My manifest.json**

```
"permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "activeTab",
    "tabCapture",
    "<all_urls>",
    "privacy"
  ]
```

**background.js**

```
chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab(self.windowId, {
          'format': 'png'
        }, function(dataURI) {
          ....
        });
```

Comment: Remove `"activeTab"` because you're using `"<all_urls>"` which is a superset of the former.

Comment: I removed the permission activeTab, but the error continues

Comment: If you properly reloaded the extension on chrome://extensions page the error can't be the same unless it's a bug in Chrome.

Comment: Yeah. This problem only happens on ms windows.

Comment: Well, it's not important if the tab is actually captured, right? At least on my Windows PC your code works. So just check chrome.runtime.lastError in the code to make it happy.

Comment: How could I do this?

Comment: `var ignoreError = chrome.runtime.lastError;`

Comment: I printed "chrome.runtime.lastError" before call the "captureVisibleTab". The lastError is undefined.

Comment: `undefined` means no error.

Comment: I'm tempted to close this as a dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28431505/unchecked-runtime-lasterror-when-using-chrome-api/

Comment: I found the source of the problem. Before the captureVisible code, my plugin mimimize the window.... 
**
chrome.windows.update(window.id, {
          state: 'minimized'
        }, function() {
          if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
            console.warn('Error (windows.update): ' + chrome.runtime.lastError.message);
          }
        });. 
**
Because I would like the my user does not see the window. When the window is minimized, the captureVisibleTab does not work for me.