# Chrome Extension postMessage from background script to content script every time in change crome tabs

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, web-extension

Good day.

I have a problem sending messages from background script to content script.
I try to send messages every time a user switches between browser tabs.

I get this error.
`Unchecked runtime.lastError: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist.`

**Below is the code for the extension itself.**

*Background Script:*

```
chrome.tabs.onActivated.addListener(function changeTab(activeInfo) {

    var port = chrome.tabs.connect(activeInfo.tabId);
    console.log(port);
    port.postMessage({tabId: activeInfo.tabId});

});
```

*Content Script:*

```
chrome.runtime.onConnect.addListener(function(port) {
    console.log(11111111);
    port.onMessage.addListener(function(msg) {
        console.log(22222222);
        if(msg == undefined || Object.keys(msg).length == 0) return;
        if(msg.checkExtensionRBPopup)
            port.postMessage({active: window.localStorage.getItem('extension_rb_popup')});
    });
});
```

*Manifest:*

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Rebatemango Extension",
  "description": "Rebatemango",
  "version": "1.0",
  "browser_action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [
        "<all_urls>"
      ],
      "js": [
        "content.js",
      ]
    }
  ],
  "permissions": [
    "background",
    "tabs",
    "activeTab",
    "declarativeContent",
    "storage",
    "clipboardWrite",
    "cookies",
    "tabCapture",
    "displaySource",
    "webNavigation"
  ],
  "background": {
    "scripts": [
      "js/jquery.js",
      "js/libs.js",
      "background.js"
    ],
    "persistent": false
  },
  "icons": {
    "16": "images/mango.png",
    "48": "images/mango.png",
    "128": "images/mango.png"
  }
}
```

Please tell me what am I doing wrong?
How to fix or track this error?

Answer (score 1):

Your content script is using `port.postMessage` but there is no listener on the other side of the port in the background script, which is why the error is shown.

**Solution:**

Use [simple messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#simple). Don't use ports, it's not needed here and your implementation is causing a memory leak since it creates a new port each time without releasing it. The simple messaging will handle this automatically.

```
chrome.tabs.sendMessage(activeInfo.tabId, {foo: 1}, response => {
  if (chrome.runtime.lastError) return;
  console.log(response);
});
```

The content script listener:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((msg, sender, sendResponse) => {
  console.log(msg);
  sendResponse({bar: 2});
});
```

---

**Other causes.**

The error message may also appear if there is no content script running at the exact moment the message was sent. It may happen because by default content scripts run after DOMContentLoaded event in the web page. Or maybe the tab contained an unsupported URL like chrome:// or chrome-extension:// from an extension page or https://chrome.google.com/webstore/ or any URL forbidden by the runtime_blocked_hosts policy. For the first problem you can add ["run_at": "document_start"](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#run_time) to your content script declaration in manifest.json. For the other cases there's nothing you can do except for [suppressing and ignoring](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28432087) the error message.

Also the background script sends `{tabId: activeInfo.tabId}` but onMessage listener in the content script doesn't read it. Instead it reads `msg.checkExtensionRBPopup` which doesn't make any sense in case it's not a copypaste artifact of posting the question.

Comment: No, content script runned after extension installed. I check it.

Comment: And tell me how to do this with an example?

Comment: I read the doc all day, but I am doing these examples and the error remains.
And after adding the parameter `"run_at": "document_idle"` everything is the same.
Nowhere is there such an example or the like that would send a message after the user moves between tabs.

Comment: Nothing changed.

Comment: Yes, of course, I understand all this. and every time I do it. Not a novice in the promotion. But at first I ran into this problem, and for the second day I can’t find a solution.

Comment: Uhm, actually I've missed something. Your content script is using `postMessage` but there is no listener in the background script on the port, which is why you see the error message. Like I said, don't use port messaging, it's not needed here. Use simple messaging.