# How to handle "Unchecked runtime.lastError: The message port closed before a response was received"?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Forgive me for any glaring mistakes as I am new to chrome extensions, but this error with Chrome's message passing API has been discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54126343/how-to-fix-unchecked-runtime-lasterror-the-message-port-closed-before-a-respon), [here](https://github.com/mozilla/webextension-polyfill/issues/130), and [here](https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/2047906?hl=en) in the past and the common response is along the lines of 'disable existing Chrome extensions, one of them is causing the error'. **Is this the best that can be accomplished? Are we supposed to just roll over and accept the fact that our extensions will conflict with others?** Returning true or returning a Promise for the listener callback function and using `sendResponse` does not solve the problem for me.

Currently, I can only get the new value stored in `chrome.storage.local` (no errors) by **disabling all other chrome extensions, removing the extension and loading back up the unpacked extension.** The code interestingly only seems to work on developer.chrome.com, it doesn't work at all on the other "matches" URLs in `manifest.json`.

I think that there is some significance in the `await` and `async` operators in solving this issue but I am unsure how to properly implement it.

**manifest.json:**

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "my extension",
    "version": "1.0",
    "description": "its my extension",
    "permissions": [
        "declarativeContent", 
        "storage", 
        "activeTab"
    ],
    "content_scripts": [
        {
          "matches": [
            "*://developer.chrome.com/*",
            "*://bbc.co.uk/*",
            "*://theguardian.com/*",
            "*://dailymail.co.uk/*"
          ],
          "js": ["content.js"]
        }
      ],
    "background": {
      "scripts": ["background.js"],
      "persistent": false
    },
    "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js; object-src 'self'",
    "page_action": {
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },
    "icons": {
        "16": "images/icon16.png",
        "32": "images/icon32.png",
        "48": "images/icon48.png",
        "128": "images/icon128.png"
      }
}
```

**popup.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>
      <title>my extension</title>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="popup.js"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
      <h1>my extension</h1>
      <h2>Article: <span id="article-headline"></span></h2>
      <button id="detect-article">Detect Article</button>
    </body>
  </html>
```

**popup.js:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#detect-article").click(function() {
        chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs){
            chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {request: "Requesting headline"}, function(response) {
                console.log("Requesting headline")
            });
        });
    });    
})

function getHeadline(changes) {
    let changedValues = Object.keys(changes);
    //console.log(changedValues);

    for (var item of changedValues) {
        console.log("new value: " + changes[item].newValue);
        $("#article-headline").text(changes[item].newValue)
    }
}

chrome.storage.onChanged.addListener(getHeadline);
```

**content.js:**

```
function handleRequest(message, sender, sendResponse) {
    console.log("Request recieved");
    let headlineList = document.getElementsByTagName("h1");
    chrome.storage.local.set({headline: headlineList[0].innerText}, function() {
        console.log("'" + headlineList[0].innerText + "' stored in local storage");
    });
    return true;
}

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(handleRequest);
```

**background.js:**

```
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function() {
    chrome.declarativeContent.onPageChanged.removeRules(undefined, function() {
      chrome.declarativeContent.onPageChanged.addRules([{
        conditions: [
          new chrome.declarativeContent.PageStateMatcher({
            pageUrl: { hostContains: 'developer.chrome.com' },
          }),
          new chrome.declarativeContent.PageStateMatcher({
            pageUrl: { hostContains: 'bbc.co.uk' },
          }),
          new chrome.declarativeContent.PageStateMatcher({
            pageUrl: { hostContains: 'theguardian.com' },
          }),
          new chrome.declarativeContent.PageStateMatcher({
              pageUrl: { hostContains: 'dailymail.co.uk' },
          }),
        ],
      actions: [new chrome.declarativeContent.ShowPageAction()]
    }]);
  });
});
```

Many thanks for taking the time to look/re-look at this issue, solutions pertaining to the aforementioned 'disable existing extensions' are not what I am looking for.

Comment: Your content script never calls `sendResponse` event though the pop-up is waiting for a response.

Comment: Have you managed to get it to work correctly using sendResponse? when i tried it the error persisted. Thanks.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

When you specify a callback for sendMessage you're telling the API that **you NEED a response** so when your content script doesn't respond using sendResponse the API thinks something terrible happened and reports it as such!

> Reminder: when editing content scripts make sure to reload both the extension on `chrome://extensions` page and the tabs that should have this content script.

**If you need a response from asynchronously running code** such as `chrome` API callback:

- Keep `return true`
- Call `sendResponse(someImportantData)` inside the callback

  ```
  chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((message, sender, sendResponse) => {
    chrome.storage.local.set({foo: 'bar'}, () => {
      sendResponse('whatever');
    });
    return true;
  });
  ```
- Same for `Promise`, but don't use `async` for the onMessage listener, [more info](/a/53024910).

  ```
  chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((message, sender, sendResponse) => {
    fetch(message.url).then(r => r.text())
      .then(t => sendResponse({ok: t}))
      .catch(e => sendResponse({err: e.message}));
    return true;
  });
  ```

**If you need a response and it can be sent immediately:**

- Replace `return true` with `sendResponse`

  ```
  chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((message, sender, sendResponse) => {
    sendResponse('whatever');
  });
  ```

**If you don't need any response:**

- Remove the callback in sendMessage

  ```
  chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {request: "Requesting headline"});
  ```
- Remove `return true` - all it does currently is telling the API to keep the messaging port open indefinitely, which will never be used by you, so it's just a memory leak source.

  ```
  chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((message, sender, sendResponse) => {
    // do something
    // don't return true
    // ManifestV2: don't call sendResponse
    // ManifestV3 bug: uncomment the next line
    // sendResponse();
  });
  ```

  For ManifestV3 [in Chrome 99, 100, 101](/a/71520415) you need a dummy sendResponse() call.

Comment: The answer lists the versions where it is required. If your results contradict the claim then it's a new bug or a mistake in your code.

Comment: I wonder why using this in conjunction with other browser extensions causes the error, but disabling all those other extensions resolves the error?

Comment: There may be many reasons why some unknown code misbehaves, but it doesn't apply to the code given in this question and answer. You should post a new question or report the problem in crbug.com.