# chrome extension - get Unchecked runtime.lastError: The message port closed before a response was received

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have added a notification to my chrome extension and I get the following error:

Unchecked runtime.lastError: The message port closed before a response was received.

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
    function (request, sender, sendResponse) {
        if (request.type === 'RONotification') {
            createNotification(request).then(() =>{
                sendResponse({status: true});
            });
        } else {
            if (functions[request.func]) {
                if (!request.args) {
                    request.args = {};
                }
                request.args.sender = sender;
                functions[request.func].call(this, request.args).then((response) => {
                    sendResponse(response);
                });
            }
        }

        return true;
    });


function createNotification(request) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        try {
            let notificationId = `notification-${Date.now()}`;
            let notificationsOptions = createNotificationOptions(request);
            chrome.notifications.create(notificationId, notificationsOptions, function (res) {
                if (res) {
                    chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function (tabs) {
                        chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {
                            notificationWasDisplayed: true,
                            notificationId: notificationId
                        }, function (response) {
                        });
                    });
                } else {
                    console.error("error create notification on background.js :", chrome.runtime.lastError);
                }
            });
        }
       catch (err) {
           console.error("exception create notification on background.js :", chrome.runtime.lastError);
       }
    });
}
```

I see that the code lines which cause the errors are :

```
   chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function (tabs) {
                        chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {
                            RONotificationWasDisplayed: true,
                            notificationId: notificationId
                        }, function (response) {
                        });
```

index.js:

```
function chromeOnChangeListener(request, sender, response) {
    if (request.NotificationWasDisplayed === true) {
            notifications.setBadgeCounter(notificationConstants.liNotificationKey).then(function (res) {
            });
    }
    return true;
}
```

which is called on the cb from chrome.notification.create...
How can I solve it?

Comment: i see the lines which is the error origin are:
chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function (tabs) {
                        chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {
                            RONotificationWasDisplayed: true,
                            notificationId: notificationId
                        }, function (response) {
                        });

Comment: its not related because i cooment out these line of code (the listner on index.js) and still get this error. the error is disappear only when I comment out the chrome.tabs,query.....(these lines of code which is written on the background.js file

Comment: index.js:
function chromeOnChangeListener(request, sender, response) {
    if (request.NotificationWasDisplayed === true) {
            notifications.setBadgeCounter(notificationConstants.liNotificationKey).then(function (res) {
            });
    }
    return true;
}

Comment: If this is the entire code then the problem occurs because there's no sendResponse inside onMessage.

Comment: More info: [Chrome extensions: 'Unchecked runtime.lastError: The message port closed before a response was received.' Is this the best we can do?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59915897)