# chrome.tabs.executeScript thows error "Unchecked runtime.lastError while running tabs.executeScript: Cannot access contents of url ..."

Tags: google-chrome-extension

So I am trying to execute a script from external source like www.script.google.com in background.js. 
But I get this error -

```
Unchecked runtime.lastError while running tabs.executeScript: Cannot access contents of url "chrome-devtools://devtools/bundled/devtools.html?&remoteBase=https://chrome…&dockSide=undocked&toolbarColor=rgba(223,223,223,1)&textColor=rgba(0,0,0,1)". Extension manifest must request permission to access this host.
```

What i am doing is sending message from popup.js to background.js
In popup.js -

```
 chrome.runtime.sendMessage({type:"addtask"});
```

In background.js -

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse){
    if(request.type == "addtask")
    {
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(null,
                       {file:"https://script.google.com/url of script....."});
    }
});
```

My manifest.json-

```
{
    "name": "Extension",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "browser_action": {
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },
     "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js"],
        "persistent": false
    },
    "content_scripts": [{
        "js": ["jquery.min.js","contentscript.js"],
        "matches": ["http://*/*","https://*/*"],
        "css" : ["feedback.css"]
    }],
    "permissions": [
          "storage","tabs","https://script.google.com"
        ],
    "web_accessible_resources": ["feedback.js","html2canvas.js","event.js"],
    "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://script.google.com/*; object-src 'self'"
}
```

Comment: Your intention is not 100% clear. Are you trying to execute the external script as a content script, or as a background script?

Comment: @Sid, If you'd want to catch the lastError, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/45603880/632951

Answer (score 39):

Plain and straight. Add `*://*/*` to permissions.

Comment: That's incredible. After hours of research, I found out my permission urls were wrong: the trailing asterisk symbol was missing so it only matched homepages. Chrome last time error was somewhat misleading, as it was censoring the urls I was trying to access with "data:text/html,chromewebdata"

Comment: Can anyone explain, is this the same as <all_urls>? I'm just trying to get data on the currently inspected window, and this permission enables me to do it but I don't want to require scary seeming permissions from users.

Comment: why is that not in the docs for the tutorial? https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted

Comment: `*://*/*` is good, but be careful with `chrome://extensions/`

Answer (score 3):

While ArtPip suggestion works in this case, often you want to execute a script on a tab or all tabs and correctly handle the error if your permissions don't allow injection on that tab or some of the tabs.

Here is an example of executing a script on all tabs and correctly handling errors:

```
tabs.forEach(tab => {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, { file: filename }, result => {
        const lastErr = chrome.runtime.lastError;
        if (lastErr) console.log('tab: ' + tab.id + ' lastError: ' + JSON.stringify(lastErr));
    });
});
```

Comment: allows to catch internal errors such as
ERR_TOO_MANY_RETRIES 
ERR_PROXY_CONNECTION_FAILED
ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE
ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
etc.

Answer (score 0):

It's super easy to inject a content script declaratively via manifest.json. The matches property determines what URLs the script can access which can also include the filesystem URL's.

```
    "content_scripts": [{

                         "matches": ["<all_urls>"],

                         "js": ["contentScript.js"]

                       }],
```

To learn more about match patterns visit https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/match_patterns

To learn more about injecting scripts https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#pi