# Chrome extension - Unchecked runtime.lastError while running tabs.executeScript: Cannot access a chrome:// URL at Object.callback (<URL>)

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm working on building chrome extension.
I have an error - Unchecked runtime.lastError while running tabs.executeScript: Cannot access a chrome:// URL     at Object.callback ().  I don't know what to do.

manifest.json

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,

    "name": "tabs",
    "description": "testing tabs",
    "version": "1.0.4",
    "icons": { "128": "icon_128.png" },
    "browser_action": {
      "default_icon": "icon.png",
      "default_title": "A popup will come here"
    },
    "background": {
      "scripts": ["background.js"]
    },
     "permissions": ["tabs", "*://*/*", "background"]
  }
```

background.js

```
chrome.tabs.query({}, function(tabs) {
        for(var i= 0; i < tabs.length; i++) { 
            chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {
            code: "console.log('wow');"
        });
    }

});
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't inject scripts in chrome:// tabs. Check `tabs[i].url` first.

Comment: You mean manifest file is wrong? or background.js file is wrong?   Could you give me some detail how to fix?

Comment: No, I mean you can't do it.

Comment: Can you specify what I can't?

Comment: You can't inject scripts in chrome:// tabs.

Comment: You mean chrome.tabs.executeScript is wrong?

Comment: I don't know how else to explain. See [Can you access chrome:// pages from an extension?](//stackoverflow.com/q/19042857)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can you access chrome:// pages from an extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19042857/can-you-access-chrome-pages-from-an-extension)

Comment: I don't understand why you can't explain?  If you know where I am wrong, you can fix the code.  please tell me how to fix it.

Comment: Well, I thought I've explained in the first comment. You can check `tabs[i].url` - and don't inject the script if it starts with `chrome`. Or you can hide the error by simply accessing chrome.runtime.lastError in the executeScript's callback ([example1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45690180), [example2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45603880)).

Comment: I already tried example2, and I still have the same error message -Cannot access a chrome:// URL.

Comment: When you edit the code of the background script you need to reload the extension.

Comment: Of course, I did.  But I still have the same error message.

Comment: If you see this error, the only reason is that you either didn't write the callback correctly as shown in example2 or the extension wasn't reloaded. The latter might be a bug in the browser so try restarting it.

Comment: BTW using `null` in executeScript makes no sense because it'll inject in the active tab. You probably want to replace it with `tabs[i].id`.

Comment: I tried example1 and example2 both.  I changed to tabs[i].id  And I closed browser, then restarted.  I still have the same error.

Comment: Well, like I said, there are no other explanations. Without seeing your current code I can't help anyway.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help.  Do you think if I publish the extension, it will work?

Comment: I think this link is correct answer.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24600495/chrome-tabs-executescript-cannot-access-a-chrome-url