# Can a chrome extension run code on a chrome error page? (i.e. ERR_INTERNET_DISCONNECTED)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to create a chrome extension that runs some javascript code on the chrome error page that has the running dinosaur mini-game. I am getting a permission error when trying to run executeScript on the tab.

[image]

Here is my code:

### manifest.js

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Extension Name",
  "description": "desc",
  "version": "1.0",
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["script.js"]
  },
  "permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "webNavigation",
    "<all_urls>"
  ]
}
```

### script.js

```
chrome.webNavigation.onErrorOccurred.addListener(function (data) {
    if (data.error === "net::ERR_INTERNET_DISCONNECTED") {
        this.chrome.tabs.executeScript(data.tabId, {
            file: "execScript.js"
        });
    }
});
```

When I open a tab, and throttle the connection to offline using developer tools, I am redirected to the dinosaur page, but the extension complains that i must request permission to access that page:

```
Unchecked runtime.lastError while running tabs.executeScript: 
   Cannot access contents of url "data:text/html,chromewebdata". 
   Extension manifest must request permission to access this host.
      at chrome-extension://jkjcmlcanhdodmlceikkfdklibkediio/script.js:9:26
```

If i try to add `"data:text/html,chromewebdata"` to the manifest file, it will break the extension saying that the url is invalid.

Is there a way to add a permission for that url? Is there another way to run my script on the dinosaur page?

Comment: No, Chrome does't allow hijacking its internal pages.

Comment: Hey, Make sure to post this as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: @Rodik, Btw you should catch lastErrors too, instead of letting them go uncaught. Catch them like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45603880/632951

Comment: Hooking https://stackoverflow.com/q/37093152/632951