# Unchecked runtime.lastError while running tabs.executeScript: Cannot access contents of url "data:text/html,chromewebdata"

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm getting this error:

```
extensions::lastError:133 Unchecked runtime.lastError while running tabs.executeScript: Cannot access contents of url "data:text/html,chromewebdata". Extension manifest must request permission to access this host.
```

I'm getting this error after disabling internet so that I can take action when the page load fails(due to heavy load) or internet down.

I've checked all similar questions and [this almost similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36762389/chrome-extension-injecting-script-get-error) but still unable to make it work.  [Another very similar one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32761782/can-a-chrome-extension-run-code-on-a-chrome-error-page-i-e-err-internet-disco) with comment that Chrome does not allow hijack of internal pages

My permissions looks like:

```
"permissions": [
        "tabs","unlimitedStorage", "notifications", "history", "activeTab", "storage", "webRequest", "webRequestBlocking", "*://*/*", "http://*/*", "https://*/*"
    ],
```

I get the error when I run this code:

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file: "showbacklink.js"});
```

or

```
  chrome.tabs.executeScript(details.tabId, {file: "showbacklink.js"});
```

where details.tabId is the active tab.

**What am I missing?**

**Edited manifest.json**

```
{
    "name": "",
    "options_page": "options.html",
    "description": "",
    "version": "1.0",
    "icons": {
        "16": "icons/logo16.png",
        "48": "icons/logo48.png",
        "128": "icons/logo128.png"
    },
    "permissions": [
        "tabs","unlimitedStorage", "notifications", "history", "activeTab", "storage", "webRequest", "webRequestBlocking",  "http://*/*", "https://*/*"
    ],
    "background": {
        "scripts": [
        "showbacklink.js",
            "client_server_common.js",
            "common.js",
            "background.js"

        ],
        "persistent": true
    },

    "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self'; object-src 'self'",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "run_at": "document_end",
            "all_frames": true,
            "matches": ["https://*/*"],
            "css": [//REMOVED],
            "js": [   //other files REMOVED
                "myscript.js",

            ]
        },


    ],
    "web_accessible_resources": [  //REMOVED
    ]


}
```

Comment: Have you tried following Haibara Ai's [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36762389/chrome-extension-injecting-script-get-error)? `chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
    for(var i = 0; i<tabs.length;i++) {
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabs[i].id, {"file": "dialog.js"});
    }
})` and `"web_accessible_resources": ["dialog.js"]` in your `manifest.json`. I think following this sample will allow you to inject script. I hope this helps.

Comment: @user5858, could you please post the entire `manifest.json` file? And which page do you want your `showbacklink.js` to be injected in?

Comment: @HaibaraAi I want to inject the code with `showbacklink.js` into the content script or the web page

Comment: Hooking https://stackoverflow.com/q/31051387/632951 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/32761782/632951

Comment: Btw for handling lastErrors, use https://stackoverflow.com/a/45603880/632951

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indeed, the "Offline" page, or any other error page shown is treated as a Chrome internal page instead of its "original" URL. As such, **you can't inject into such pages to change them** for security reasons. Imagine for a moment that an extension would be able to interact with SSL warning pages - you *really, really* don't want that.

If your goal is to provide some sort of alternative error page, you need to hook a listener for such navigation errors and redirect to your own page.

I would recommend looking at `webNavigation` and `webRequest` API.

Comment: During this error I want to provide them a link which they should click to restart  to step-1. At the moment I've added this link in the popup but the users will need to click on the options icon.

Comment: If you have a link and you display some replacement error page, you can use that link there.

Comment: You mean redirecting a page to some custom page? That I want to avoid as original error/problem may be lost from user's sight. Best should be to insert a link in the error page so that user can be aware of error and possible click the remedy link immediately.

Comment: What you ask for is not possible in any circumstances.

Comment: @Xan, Data:text/html are used for other things too, not just chrome internal webpages.

Comment: @Xan, Sigh, they're fixing all the stuff that no one needs yet leave important ones used by [⨕ the commoners](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/chromium-extensions/-CfZ-wO0Wsw) unfixed.