# Chrome extension injecting script get error

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

On injecting the script by using command

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript(
  null, {file: "dialog.js"});
```

throwing error

Unchecked runtime.lastError while running tabs.executeScript: Cannot access contents of url "chrome-devtools://devtools/bundled/inspector.html?&remoteBase=https://chrom…om/serve_file/@4fc366553993dd1524b47a280fed49d8ec28421e/&dockSide=undocked". Extension manifest must request permission to access this host.
    at onNativeMessage (chrome-extension://knldjmfmopnpolahpmmgbagdohdnhkik/background.js:31:5)

```
manifiest.json
{
  "key": "MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQDcBHwzDvyBQ6bDppkIs9MP4ksKqCMyXQ/A52JivHZKh4YO/9vJsT3oaYhSpDCE9RPocOEQvwsHsFReW2nUEc6OLLyoCFFxIb7KkLGsmfakkut/fFdNJYh0xOTbSN8YvLWcqph09XAY2Y/f0AL7vfO1cuCqtkMt8hFrBGWxDdf9CQIDAQAB",
  "name": "TerminusProLink",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "description": "Link to ProLaw App",
  "background": {
  "scripts": [ "background.js", "background.html"]
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "all_frames": true,
      "js": [ "jquery-1.5.1.js", "jquery-ui-1.8.11.js", "content.js" ],
      "matches": [ "http://*/*", "https://*/*" ]
    }
  ],

  "permissions": [
    "background", "tabs", "http://*/*", "https://*/*",

  ]
}
```

Any one having solution please suggest.

Comment: Btw you can catch that lastError: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45603880/632951

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please explicitly set the `tabId` parameter of `executeScript`, which [by default](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-executeScript) would be the active tab of the current window.

If you couldn't get `tabId` directly, use `chrome.tabs.query` to query tab state.

```
chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
    for(var i = 0; i<tabs.length;i++) {
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabs[i].id, {"file": "dialog.js"});
    }
});
```

And don't forget add `"web_accessible_resources": ["dialog.js"]` in your `manifest.json`

Comment: Thanks, it is working. But need to pass message to dialog.js.  How to pass   message to the dialog.js method?

Comment: @VishwajeetBose, if you mean passing parameters when calling `executeScript`, take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17567624/pass-parameter-using-executescript-chrome

Comment: After use that not even execute dialog.js code.   
            chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabs[i].id, { code: "var msg=1;" }, function () {
                chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabs[i].id, { "file": "dialog.js" });
            });
        }
In dialog.js
function callCheck() {
    debugger;
    var DialogBox = document.createElement("div");
    var TextPara = document.createElement("p");
    TextPara.innerHTML = "ss";
    DialogBox.appendChild(TextPara);
    $(DialogBox).dialog({
    });
}
alert(msg);
callCheck();

Comment: @VishwajeetBose, please be aware when inner `executeScript` is executed, `i` has been equal with `tabs.length` and obviously `tabs[i]` is undefined. You could define a local variable like `var tabId = tabs[i].id`, then use it in `executeScript`.