# I want to avoid chrome.runtime.lastError when I execute chrome.tabs.executeScript(...)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, content-script, execute-script

I am developting chrome-extension.
I try to inject script-tag using `chrome.tabs.executeScript`, but it occurs some error in specific URLs.

I use [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26517988/unchecked-runtime-lasterror-while-running-tabs-executescript/45603880#45603880) as reference, but there are many error-logs in console...

I know my extension won't work in the Chrome web store or on Chrome internal pages, and I'm ok with that, but that display makes it look to users like the extension is broken.
I want to avoid errors in some way (for exmaple, URL access filter??), but I don't know what to do.

Can anyone give me some advices??

```js
chrome.tabs.executeScript(e.tabId, {"allFrames": false, "matchAboutBlank": true, "runAt": 'document_start', "frameId": e.frameId, "file": "/inject.js"}, function(){
  if(chrome.runtime.lastError){
    console.error(chrome.runtime.lastError.message)
  }       
})
```

[image]

Comment: Simply remove or comment console.error line, but leave the `if` check.

Comment: Is it impossible filtering Chrome web store or on Chrome internal pages??

Comment: There's no need for that. The approach I suggested is the simplest.

Comment: OK, thanks for your advice!I will try it!